# Use elements of Array inside function definition

Tags: functions, packed-arrays

I'm trying to define a function which modifies and sums over the elements of an array. Here is a very simplified version.

```
myF[kmax_] = Sum[v[[k]]/k, {k, 1, kmax}]
```

As you can see, each element between 1 and the function argument (`kmax`) is divided by its index and then summed with the others.

The problem is that mathematica isn't accepting that `v[[k]]` and complains that `k` isn't an integer.

```
Part::pspec: Part specification k is neither an integer nor a list of integers.
```

I tried replacing `k` with `Round[k]`, but the problem remains. I even tried redefining the vector, where the elements are already divided by `k`, and then just summing over the first `kmax` elements:

```
myF[kmax_] = Total[Take[v, kmax]]
```

And I'm still getting error messages about the argument not being of the right type

```
Take::seqs: Sequence specification (+n, -n, {+n}, {-n}, {m, n}, or {m, n, s}) expected at position 2 in Take
```

So, am I doing something wrong? **Is there any way to access array elements within a function definition?**

Comment: Try with `myF[kmax_] := ... `.

Comment: Also `myF[kmax_Integer] := ...` will give you some defence against real values creeping into your function.

Comment: You should generaly avoid using `Set` (`=`) for function definitions, and you should avoid defining functions which depend on variables implicitly (like on your `v` here). For the latter, you can read some relevant discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when *Mathematica* processes

```
myF[kmax_] = Sum[v[[k]]/k, {k, 1, kmax}]
```

it will immediately evaluate the right-hand side. And since it doesn't have a numeric value for `kmax` yet, it can't evaluate the `Sum` yet, which leads it to tell you that in `v[[k]]`, `k` is not an integer, because it's still a symbol!

If you instead use a delayed set `:=`, the right-hand side will not be evaluated until the function is called where `kmax` has been given a value, so

```
 myF[kmax_] := Sum[v[[k]]/k, {k, 1, kmax}]
```

Then when you call `myF[10]` *Mathematica* evaluates `Sum[v[[k]]/k, {k, 1, 10}]`, which means `k` gets an integer value before it evaluates `v[[k]]`.

Answer (score 7):

While you said your example was a simplified version, if the full form is similar, I would consider using vector processing:

```
myF[kmax_] := Total[v[[;;kmax]]/Range[kmax]]
```

where `v[[;;kmax]]/Range[kmax]` is evaluated term wise, i.e. it gives $\frac{v_i}{i}$. There are a number of optimizations internally that make this faster than `Sum`.

Note, the use of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`), like in jVincent's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15699/52).

**Edit**: Additionally, I would consider using a `Dot` product instead:

```
myF[kmax_] := v[[;;kmax]].(1/Range[kmax])
```

which incorporates the vector processing from before, and improves readability.

Comment: Or he could define `myF = v.(1/Range[Length[v]])` and call `myF[[i]]` instead of `myF[i]`.

Comment: @Jens, good point. I think programatically and conceptually that is superior.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the distinction between `=` and `:=` shown by jVincent, you can prevent `Part` from receiving a bad argument by introducing an auxiliary function with a restrictive pattern.  This is most commonly done with the pattern `_?NumericQ` and you will see many examples if you search this site for **NumericQ**.  Here I will use `_Integer` as that is more appropriate as an argument for `Part`.

```
v = {9, 7, 5, 3, 1};

part[x_, n_Integer] := x[[n]]

Sum[part[v, k]/k, {k, 1, kmax}]
```

> ```
> Sum[part[{9, 7, 5, 3, 1}, k]/k, {k, 1, kmax}]
> ```

This expression is returned without errors.